# AsyncTask. Problems with receiving from Java Server

Tags: android, sockets, tcp, android-asynctask

I want to use AsyncTask for receiving ArrayList's(in this case) from Java server. To be sure, that I received something from server I'm trying to display it with Toast.

The Code is following:

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private DataReceiving dRec;
private DataTransfer dTrans;
private EditText inputData;
private Button sendParametersBtn;
private Button startComputationBtn;
private TextView displayText;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    inputData=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.InputText);
    sendParametersBtn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    startComputationBtn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    displayText=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);


    sendParametersBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dRec = new DataReceiving();
            dRec.execute(); 

        }
    });
private class DataReceiving extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList>
{       

    @Override
    protected ArrayList doInBackground(Void... params) {
        ArrayList b = new ArrayList();
        try {
            b = receive();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }           
        return b;

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList result) {              
          super.onPostExecute(result);  
          Toast toast=Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
          toast.show();
    }

 public ArrayList receive () throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
{
    ServerSocket s= new ServerSocket(8888);
    Socket incoming =s.accept();                
    ObjectInputStream ios = new ObjectInputStream(incoming.getInputStream());
    ArrayList b = (ArrayList) ios.readObject();             
    ios.close();
    incoming.close();
    s.close();
    return b;
}
```

While clicking the sendParametersBtn nothing happening. 
P.S. I can successfully transmit from Android to Server. So its not a connection or permission problem.

Thank you for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out! I removed receive method into doInBackground.

Answer (score 0):

Hi If your getting some thing from server you have to call web server url for fetching data. After data arrives response have some type it will JSON/XML if they are restful services if they are SOAP services they are in envelope. So after response return get that and parse them as per logic.

Look for HTTP get/post (for ping to server and get data )and parsing (JSON/XML).

Comment: It is not a webserver, which runs HTTP. It is just another machine in local network that runs Java application. I want to use sockets to do all the data transfers.